# Firebase database emulator does not start

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am struggling to test my firebase functions locally. My database emulator appears to work

```
✗ firebase serve --only database
i  database: Emulator logging to database-debug.log
✔  database: Emulator started at http://localhost:9000
```

But it is not started when I try to start all my emulators together

```
✗ firebase emulators:start                
i  Starting emulators: ["functions","hosting"]
✔  functions: Using node@10 from host.
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
✔  hosting: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
i  functions: Watching ".../functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to .../ignore/fbkey.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
✔  functions[subscribe]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/xxx/us-central1/subscribe).
✔  functions[unsubscribe]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/xxx/us-central1/unsubscribe).
i  functions[sendNotification]: function ignored because the database emulator does not exist or is not running.   <-------- why does this happen
✔  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

I get the same result with `firebase serve`, and do not know what to do next?

Comment: Please file an issue on the firebase-tools github.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

The newer `emulators:start` command is the recommended way to start the Realtime Database emulator.

So first run this command to set up the emulators you want:

```
firebase init emulators
```

Then run the following command to start them all:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Or if you just want to start certain ones:

```
firebase emulators:start --only database,functions
```

As of this writing supported emulators are:

- Realtime Database (`database`)
- Cloud Firestore (`firestore`)
- Cloud Functions (`functions`)
- Hosting (`hosting`)
- Cloud Pub/Sub (`pubsub`)